# Memory increase rapidly using gluTess*, display list and frame buffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm programming with OpenGL under MSVC 2010.

One of my goal is to pick objects in the scene. I design it in the way like assigning each object a unique color, rendering them in a framebuffer, then reading the color where the cursor is, and the corresponding object can be acquired.

Now the picking is working well. However, **as long as a picking happens, the memory increases rapidly**. In detail, the following code render objects into a framebuffer:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i)
{
    //some code computing color;
    Color color;

    for (unsigned j = 0; j < objects[i].listOfPrimitives.size(); ++j)
    {
        objects[i].listOfPrimitives[j]->color = color;
    }

    objects[i].Render();
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < objects[i].listOfPrimitives.size(); ++j)
    {
        objects[i].listOfPrimitives[j]->color = colorStorage[i][j];
    }
}
```

where *objects* are objects to be rendered. Since every object has a certain number of primitives(which may be a cylinder, sphere etc.), this piece of code just changes the color of each object's primitives to a unique computed one, render the object, then change it back (*colorSotrage* stores the original colors). And there are some code in the following to deal with the object, which I'm sure has nothing to do with this issue.

The *render* method are implemented as following for most object:

```
glColor3ub(color[0], color[1], color[2]);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < mesh.faces.size(); ++i)
{
    glNormal3d(mesh.faces[i].normal.x, mesh.faces[i].normal.y, mesh.faces[i].normal.z);
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        glVertex3d(mesh.vertices[mesh.faces[i].verts[j]].x, 
        mesh.vertices[mesh.faces[i].verts[j]].y, 
        mesh.vertices[mesh.faces[i].verts[j]].z);
    }
}
glEnd();
```

But for some object, there are some concave polygons (even with holes), so I use the *gluTess** group functions in GLU to render them, and to speed up the rendering procedure, I use display list to that part.

Now, as I've mentioned. this picking procedure increases the memory cost rapidly. There are two more phenomenons I can't explain:

1. If I comment line 8 in the first piece of code, the memory will not change at all when the piece of code runs (of course, this code will not work);
2. After the memory increases, if I do some refresh to the scene (I design an interactive trackball), the memory will drop off again.

So I'm wondering which part could be the reason of this issue? The display list? the gluTess*() calling? or even something related to framebuffer?

Comment: It is far more likely that your own code has a memory leak as opposed to finding the blame with the opengl related routines. Could be as simple as forgetting to delete a display list. Your sample code is incomplete and can't be used for more than just guessing. I suggest you use the debugger in MSVC to step through your own code and understand what happens every frame, complimentary there are opengl-specific debuggers also like (amd's) gdebugger or codexl.

Comment: @LawrenceKok Thanks, but shouldn't dislay list be built and stored but not re-built every time use it? And another weird thing is that when running in debug mode, the memory does not increase like this...

Comment: Correct, display lists should only be built a single time, but in the event that you *do* rebuilt it, you still need to deallocate the old one. That said, it was just an example of a leak that you could have created by yourself.

Comment: Thx. I think that shouldn't be the problem. I've checked carefully and there isn't such thing like glGen*() etc. that is called redundantly and lead to leaking.